# SQL - Add to existing rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, count, sum

I have an ever growing table where I want to update the data to make an overall count. When the update takes place the overall count data being inserted the rows may already be included in the table and new rows will be also be added. I am unsure though how to add to the previous rows and create them if they are new whilst adding the sum totale if they already exist. For example

```
column1|column2|count
---------------------
A      |A      |5
A      |B      |7
B      |A      |4
```

And I will to add the following data from another table but column1/2 will always be changing:

```
{To be Added}
column1|column2|count
---------------------
A      |A      |10
B      |A      |2
C      |A      |5
```

So the final table will look like when :

```
column1|column2|count
--------------------
A      |A      |15
A      |B      |7
B      |A      |9
C      |A      |5
```

Looking into this gave me the solution to use `SUM()` but as the columns will always be changing this is where I have come across my issue. Also would this also be easier to create a staging table to collaborate as this data instead of trying to update this all in one query?

Appreciate any help,
Many Thanks,
Jordan

Comment: where does the `C|A|9` row come from?

Comment: Without knowing history of the columns values and relating that history to the current value, there isn't really a way to sum up like you are wanting.

Comment: Sorry, yes your right. Very bad maths from me when writing this. Updated the question. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: This is representing log data and column1 is like its name and 2 is a subcategory. And the count is when an action happens from each one. The overall result is to to creating a simple analytical view of the product in use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also do it in this way with the help of these queries.

```
--first update common rows
update t1
set t1.count=t1.count+t2.counts
select * from tbl1 t1 inner join 
(select column1,column2,SUm(count) as counts from tbl2 
group by column1,column2)
t2 on t1.column1=t2.column1 and t1.column2=t2.column2

--now insert remaining rows
insert into t1(column1,column2,count) 
select t2.column1,t2.column2,t2.counts as count 
from tbl1 t1 right join 
   (select column1,column2,SUm(count) as counts from tbl2 
    group by column1,column2) t2
 on t1.column1=t2.column1 and t1.column2=t2.column2
where t1.column1 is NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use a `MERGE` statement for this:

```
Merge Into Table As Target 
Using (Select Column1, Column2, Count From OtherTable) As Source 
    On (Target.Column1 = Source.Column1 And Target.Column2 = Source.Column2) 
When Matched Then
    Update Set Count = Target.Count + Source.Count
When Not Matched Then
    Insert (Column1, Column2, Count) 
    Values (Source.Column1, Source.Column2, Source.Count)
;
```

This will merge data into your main table from your other table based on their Column1 and Column2 values.  If the value does not exist already, it will `INSERT` the record.  Otherwise, it will `UPDATE` the table with the sum of the two values.